# javascript regexp find 3rd char at the end of the string

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I use regexp to turn "1.500.00" into "1.500,00"?
The comma is always needed before 2 last digits. So I need regexp to look at the end of the string and replace 3rd char with ",". But I can't figure out what expression to use for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
yourString.replace(/\.(\d\d)$/, ",$1");
```

Comment: That would produce "1,500,00", but it need it to be "1.500,00"

Comment: BTW: Your comment is wrong. The `$` sign at the end of the regex says, that it should only match at the end of the string. So it wouldn't match .50 in the middle of your string.

Comment: `console.log("1.500.00".replace("\.(\d\d)$", ",$1"))` is giving me `1.500.00`.

Answer (score 1):

How about *not* using a regexp:

```
var num = '1.500.00'.split('.'), 
    num1 = num.slice(0,num.length-1), 
    num2 = num[num.length-1];

alert(num1.join('.')+','+num2); //=> 1.500,00
```

Or without intermediate variables (`num1`, `num2`):

```
alert(num.slice(0,num.length-1).join('.')+','+num[num.length-1]); /=> 1.500,00
```

Or

```
alert([ num.slice(0,num.length-1).join('.'), num[num.length-1] ].join(','));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str = "1.500.00";

var patt1=/.\d{2}$/;
var patt2=/\d{2}$/;
document.write(str.replace(str.match(patt1),','+str.match(patt2)));
```

result:

```
1.500,00
```

Answer (score 0):

For text replace

`"I have 1.400.00$ and 57.60 pounds".replace(/\.(\d{2}\D?)/g, ",$1")`